# Correlation of Financial Returns using Period-End vs. Period-Average Values

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, correlation, finance, approximation

I have two time series of financial returns for assets $A$ and $B$ defined below for $n$ periods. The return $a_i$ is the percent growth in the asset price of $A$ using period-end values for $i-1$ and $i$.

I have also calculated financial returns $A'$ and $B'$ which are an approximation of the *period-average* value of period $i$ compared to the *period-average* value of period $i-1$. In this example I am using the average of start of period and end of period values to get this value.

My empirical testing across at least 10 different pairs of return time series has given that the correlation of $A$ and $B$ is very close to that of $A'$ and $B'$ but I have not been able to prove that this should be the case in general, or that there are any specific conditions in which this would be the case.

My question is whether it is possible to prove mathematically that this relationship should hold in general or under specific conditions.

$A=\{a_i ∶i=1,...,n\}$

$B=\{b_i ∶i=1,...,n\}$

$A'=\{(1+a_{i-1})(2+a_i)/(2+a_{i-1})-1:i=2,...n\}$

$B'=\{(1+b_{i-1})(2+b_i)/(2+b_{i-1})-1:i=2,...n\}$

$\rho_{A,B}\approx\rho_{A',B'}$

For the benefit of this approximation, I would have no problem assuming either normality or log-normality of the pair of time series. We can assume no serial correlation in either time series. The returns are having an average in the 10-20% range and a standard deviation in the 5-40%.

Thanks

Comment: So... what is your question? Testing for differences in these two correlations?

Comment: My question is whether it is possible to prove mathematically that this relationship should hold in general or under specific conditions. Have edited for clarity.

Comment: *We can certainly assume independence.* I would have thought that that is the one thing you cannot assume here if your interest is correlations.

Comment: I mean there is no serial correlation in either time series